# How to group by date from datetime and order by date time

Tags: sql, sql-server

What I am trying to do is group by date only from a datetime column and then ordering by the datetime column.

Below SQL is grouping by the date from the datetime column with the minimum time ( I am assuming )

```
SELECT MIN(CAST(Date AS DATE))   
FROM [TEST].[dbo].[PROD]   
GROUP BY CAST(Date AS DATE)
```

Output

```
DATE 
15/01/2018
16/01/2018    
17/01/2018    
18/01/2018
```

Is there a way where I can add the order by ‘Date’ and show the date and time in the results?

Ideal output

```
DATE 
15/01/2018 18:52    
16/01/2018 18:52   
17/01/2018 18:52   
18/01/2018 18:52
```

is this possible? if so could someone show me please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `cast` in the `select()`:

```
SELECT MIN(Date)
FROM [TEST].[dbo].[PROD]
GROUP BY CAST(Date AS DATE)
ORDER BY MIN(Date);
```

By the way "Date" is a really bad name for a column that has a time component.

Comment: but how do i add a order by in this query

Comment: is there a way where i can say do a count where the time is over 10am?

Comment: You can do the count for the group of date `SELECT MIN(Date) , Count(Date) `

Comment: sum(case when hour(date)>10 then 1 else 0 end)   --Take note that hour returns an int on a 24 hour clock.

Comment: I mixed up languages replace hour(date) with datepart(HH,date)